# laravel error when i try to update unique field

Tags: php, laravel, validation

when I just change the title field the content field will be an error because it only accepts unique value, if I don't use unique validation then there will be a possibility of paper with the same title, and I don't want it.

My method in controller :

```
 public function update(Paper $paper)
   {
       // validation
       $data = request()->validate([
           'title' => ['required', 'unique:papers'],
           'content' => ['required']
       ]);
       $data['slug'] = \Str::slug(request('title'));

       $paper->update($data);

       return redirect()->route('papers.show', $paper);
   }
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Which one accept unique value `title` or `content` ??

Comment: @A.ANoman The `title` field, obviously.

Comment: Look @festie. `content field will be an error because it only accepts unique value`

Comment: @A.ANoman With the setup above there is no 'unique' rule on the content field and therefore won't be checked. If there's actually an error for the content field, it might come from a misconfigured database, but not from Laravel.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

This happens, because Laravel doesn't know what exact item you're trying to update. It simply checks if the given title exists already in the database.  This is the case when you update your entity without changing it's title. Basically it is doing exactly what you asked it to do.

To prevent this, Laravel supports the option to exclude a given `id` from the rule. Instead of using `unique:title`, try using the following in your rule-set for an update. Be sure to import the Rule class:

```php
'title' => [
    // ...
    Rule::unique('papers')->ignore($paper->id),
];
```

---

You can find more details about this procedure in the official documentation:

- https://laravel.com/docs/master/validation#rule-unique

Comment: Hey @festie. I tried your solution. But It totally false. I have two name `Shape` and `Round`. When I rename `Shape` to `Round` it updates as `Round`. Now I have two name `Round` and `Round`.

Comment: @A.ANoman Please make sure you're using this correctly as specified in the docs.